# How to handle immature player as a first-time GM?

Tags: problem-players, social, star-wars-edge-of-the-empire

It is my first time GM for a Star Wars: Edge Of The Empire campaign, and I've been having problems with one of the players. Most are "mature" when roleplaying, meaning they take the story, and the setting seriously.

One, however, insists on acting "over the top". The character himself is not a problem, but how the player roleplays is very disruptive, even trying to abandon the story for his own antics. 

For example, the other players will be having a conversation with an NPC, choosing to do so in-character. The third will speak in a ridiculous voice and either ignore the conversation entirely, or try and derail it for whatever task their one-track mind character wants to do instead. The other players have tried to rein him in, to no success.

Before the campaign started, I had mentioned that, as I am new to GM-ing, I would prefer nobody gets too ridiculous. I do not think this player is being malicious and does not see how disruptive he is being, but I am unsure how to deal with his behavior without ignoring his character completely.

How should I handle this situation?

Comment: Accepting an answer dissuades others from posting answers, you should give it a couple days usually.

Comment: Can you tell us the rough age range of the group (and especially the trouble player?)  Can you also tell us if you and your players are friends outside the game, or if your relationship is strictly gaming-based?

Comment: Is it possible that the player's suffering from My Guy syndrome (and doesn't know that that kind of behavior is inappropriate despite being "his character")?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## Do a *Session 0*

You need to do a *Session 0* -- in the answers to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105388/30214) you can find more info about it. Basically it means that you need to gather your players for a talk and bring up all of the issues. Your problem player, assuming that they don't fit in the group's playstyle, has two options:

- Change
- Leave the group

You need to say direct that there are no other alternatives. And if the player continues to be disruptive, they *really* have to leave the group.

You need to note that it is an out-of-character issue, and hence should also be discussed out-of-character.

As noted in my answer to the linked question, the *Session 0* can actually be done at any time of the campaign, not only before it starts -- provided that you need it.

Comment: "Session 0s" are before the campaign starts, and he already basically did this ("requested it not get too ridiculous").

Answer (score 9):

Sit down, talk with your player, voice your concerns, let them respond and use their response to gauge whether or not your first instinct of them acting the way they are is simply innocent or something else more intentional.

If the talk proves productive and you get a good feeling, enjoy the rest of your campaign!

If the talk is productive but you're not quite sure you and your player are on the same page, just keep an eye on them and reinforce the fact that next time it won't be a talk and you'll have to take more severe measures.

If you don't get anywhere at all, either your player is just not socially aware (which seems highly unlikely) or they're just a dick. If the latter, then you know where you stand with them and feel free to kick them out if that's a possibility. Alternatively, if they readily admit they are a dick, you may have something you can channel into something conducive to an awesome game if you're willing to try and focus it toward in-game situations where the player can shine honestly (because a self-admitted dick is, paradoxically, unlikely to be a completely terrible person in my experience and does want to have a good time with their friends at the table).

And there's always the option of encouraging the players to RP in-game in such a way as to single out the PC or actively have their characters forcibly deal with theirs (say, making a Melee check against their stomach!). Or you can simply award them less EXP per session (very effective for many players). Could be hurt feelings but you can smooth that out with the aforementioned talk at the start of this answer after the fact.